# Failed to start Apache web server managed by cPanel EasyApache

Tags: apache, ssl, cpanel

I'm on CentOS 7. After updating the SSL certificate on my server, the httpd service refused to restart.
Below is the result of the systemctl start httpd.service command:

```
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details
```

Here is the output of the systemctl status httpd.service.

```
httpd.service - Apache web server managed by cPanel EasyApache
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2023-12-25 15:59:51 CET; 26s ago
Process: 11144 ExecStart=/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/restartsrv_httpd --no-verbose (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Dec 25 15:59:51 vmi676465.contaboserver.net systemd[1]: Starting Apache web server managed by cPanel EasyApache...
Dec 25 15:59:51 vmi676465.contaboserver.net systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 25 15:59:51 vmi676465.contaboserver.net systemd[1]: Failed to start Apache web server managed by cPanel EasyApache.
Dec 25 15:59:51 vmi676465.contaboserver.net systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Dec 25 15:59:51 vmi676465.contaboserver.net systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

Here is also the output of journalctl -xe

```
Dec 25 12:21:24 myserver systemd[1]: Can't open PID file /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/mailman/data/master-qrunner.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
Dec 25 12:21:24 myserver systemd[1]: Failed to start mailman services.

sshd[11911]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
sshd[11913]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  user=root
sshd[11913]: pam_succeed_if(sshd:auth): requirement "uid >= 1000" not met by user "root"
```

The following is part of the apache error_log

```
[root@xxxxxx ~]# tail -n 50 /etc/apache2/logs/error_log
[Wed Dec 13 00:02:58.391181 2023] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 4011:tid 47495612335872] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:35416] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown'
[Wed Dec 13 00:54:41.016917 2023] [authz_core:error] [pid 4011:tid 47495599728384] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:45011] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/ppducpanel/public_html/wp-includes/error_log, referer: https://myserver.com/wp-includes/?C=N%3BO%3DD
[Wed Dec 13 01:57:23.974143 2023] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 4012:tid 47495601829632] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:62097] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown'
[Wed Dec 13 02:42:55.756764 2023] [authz_core:error] [pid 4008:tid 47495705020160] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20435] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/ppducpanel/public_html/wp-includes/ID3/error_log, referer: https://myserver.com/wp-includes/ID3/?C=N%3BO%3DD
[Wed Dec 13 03:09:25.634489 2023] [proxy:error] [pid 4008:tid 47495612335872] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: http: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:2079 (127.0.0.1:2079) failed
[Wed Dec 13 03:09:25.637231 2023] [proxy_http:error] [pid 4008:tid 47495612335872] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx9:60141] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1, referer: http://www.google.com.hk
[Wed Dec 13 03:09:25.637367 2023] [proxy:error] [pid 4008:tid 47495612335872] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: http: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:2079 (127.0.0.1:2079) failed
[Wed Dec 13 03:09:25.637377 2023] [proxy_http:error] [pid 4008:tid 47495612335872] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:60141] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1, referer: http://www.google.com.hk
[Wed Dec 13 03:19:38.349410 2023] [:error] [pid 4008:tid 47495622842112] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:35797] File does not exist: /var/www/html/ip.php, referer: https://google.com/
[Wed Dec 13 03:25:20.047061 2023] [cgid:error] [pid 4009:tid 47495698716416] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:33762] AH01264: script not found or unable to stat: /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/favicon.ico
[Wed Dec 13 03:51:22.356617 2023] [proxy:error] [pid 4008:tid 47495603930880] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: http: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:2079 (127.0.0.1:2079) failed
[Wed Dec 13 03:51:22.375402 2023] [proxy_http:error] [pid 4008:tid 47495603930880] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:52879] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1, referer: http://www.google.com.hk
[Wed Dec 13 03:51:22.375712 2023] [proxy:error] [pid 4008:tid 47495603930880] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: http: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:2079 (127.0.0.1:2079) failed
[Wed Dec 13 03:51:22.375726 2023] [proxy_http:error] [pid 4008:tid 47495603930880] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:52879] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1, referer: http://www.google.com.hk
[Wed Dec 13 04:01:33.222668 2023] [proxy:error] [pid 4012:tid 47495700817664] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: http: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:2079 (127.0.0.1:2079) failed
[Wed Dec 13 04:01:33.222750 2023] [proxy_http:error] [pid 4012:tid 47495700817664] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:61685] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1
[Wed Dec 13 04:01:33.222836 2023] [proxy:error] [pid 4012:tid 47495700817664] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: http: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:2079 (127.0.0.1:2079) failed
[Wed Dec 13 04:01:33.222842 2023] [proxy_http:error] [pid 4012:tid 47495700817664] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:61685] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1
[Wed Dec 13 04:01:33.249752 2023] [proxy:error] [pid 4008:tid 47495700817664] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: http: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:2079 (127.0.0.1:2079) failed
[Wed Dec 13 04:01:33.249788 2023] [proxy_http:error] [pid 4008:tid 47495700817664] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:63964] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1
[Wed Dec 13 04:01:33.249879 2023] [proxy:error] [pid 4008:tid 47495700817664] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: http: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:2079 (127.0.0.1:2079) failed
[Wed Dec 13 04:01:33.249889 2023] [proxy_http:error] [pid 4008:tid 47495700817664] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:63964] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1
[Wed Dec 13 05:59:47.234822 2023] [proxy:error] [pid 4010:tid 47495601829632] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: http: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:2079 (127.0.0.1:2079) failed
[Wed Dec 13 05:59:47.240819 2023] [proxy_http:error] [pid 4010:tid 47495601829632] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:57744] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1
[Wed Dec 13 05:59:47.241308 2023] [proxy:error] [pid 4010:tid 47495601829632] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: http: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:2079 (127.0.0.1:2079) failed
[Wed Dec 13 05:59:47.241327 2023] [proxy_http:error] [pid 4010:tid 47495601829632] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:57744] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1
[Wed Dec 13 05:59:47.457497 2023] [proxy:error] [pid 4009:tid 47495603930880] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: http: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:2079 (127.0.0.1:2079) failed
[Wed Dec 13 05:59:47.457592 2023] [proxy_http:error] [pid 4009:tid 47495603930880] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:53604] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1
[Wed Dec 13 05:59:47.457675 2023] [proxy:error] [pid 4009:tid 47495603930880] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: http: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:2079 (127.0.0.1:2079) failed
[Wed Dec 13 05:59:47.457681 2023] [proxy_http:error] [pid 4009:tid 47495603930880] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:53604] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1
[Wed Dec 13 07:42:43.215144 2023] [:error] [pid 4012:tid 47495713425152] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:42764] File does not exist: /var/www/html/ip.php, referer: https://google.com/
[Wed Dec 13 08:14:54.314029 2023] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 4012:tid 47495711323904] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:51874] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown'
[Wed Dec 13 08:14:55.869833 2023] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 4008:tid 47495711323904] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:33365] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown'
[Wed Dec 13 08:14:56.811407 2023] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 4011:tid 47495711323904] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:44992] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown'
[Wed Dec 13 08:53:35.617349 2023] [mpm_worker:notice] [pid 21141:tid 47495352321088] AH00295: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
AH00016: Configuration Failed
AH00016: Configuration Failed
AH00016: Configuration Failed
AH00016: Configuration Failed
AH00016: Configuration Failed
```

What can be the root cause of this failure to restart the httpd service? Any tips to settle the issue?

Edit:
Here is the outpu when I tried to restart the apache service via WHM:

```
Apache Restart Output: Apache could not be started due to an error: The “/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/restartsrv_httpd --start” command (process 15564) reported error number 255 when it ended. 
Waiting for “httpd” to start ………Waiting for httpd,litespeed,lscgid to shutdown ... not running. ……failed. 
Cpanel::Exception::Services::StartError Service Status undefined status from Cpanel::ServiceManager::Services::Httpd Service Error (XID wqcbax) The “httpd” service failed to start. 
Startup Log Dec 25 17:07:59 myserver systemd[1]: Starting Apache web server managed by cPanel EasyApache... 
Dec 25 17:07:59 myserver systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1 
Dec 25 17:07:59 myserver systemd[1]: Failed to start Apache web server managed by cPanel EasyApache. 
Dec 25 17:07:59 myserver systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state. 
Dec 25 17:07:59 myserver systemd[1]: httpd.service failed. Log Messages 
Dec 25 17:07:59 vmi676465 systemd: Failed to start Apache web server managed by cPanel EasyApache. 
Dec 25 17:07:59 vmi676465 systemd: Starting Apache web server managed by cPanel EasyApache... httpd has failed. 
Contact your system administrator if the service does not automagically recover. 
Log: AH00016: Configuration Failed AH00016: Configuration Failed AH00016: Configuration Failed AH00016: Configuration Failed AH00016: Configuration Failed AH00016: Configuration Failed AH00016: Configuration Failed AH00016: Configuration Failed AH00016: Configuration Failed AH00016: Configuration Failed
```

Comment: You should run `apachectl configtest` after making any changes to config files.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk : apachectl configtest returns Syntax OK

Comment: Is there any custom log in your environment  ? are you able to start httpd service using command line instead of service script.